Is there a good way to store very small data in python?
I am making a snake game in python. I want to score the user's best score and the time taken to get that score. I want to use an appropriate method to store the data. What is a good way to do this?
Is SQLite3 for this an overkill and should I just stick to text files?

I suggest taking look at shelve which is part of standard library and allows you to store and retrieve dict, simple example, writing
import shelve
scores = shelve.open("highscores")
scores["Jane"] = {"points": 100, "seconds": 70}
scores["Joe"] = {"points": 90, "seconds": 50}

reading
import shelve
scores = shelve.open("highscores")
for name, score in scores.items():
    print(name, "played for", score["seconds"], "seconds and got", score["points"], "points")

gives output
Jane played for 70 seconds and got 100 points
Joe played for 50 seconds and got 90 points

Keep in mind that shelve is python-specific so it is no-go if you wish to access highscores using another language.

to be honest database shall be better than text file, because its easier to write things out from database and making it is just a pleasure, i recommend you to make database with sqlitedict if u think sqilte3 is too hard.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

You can definitely use SQLite for this as it's file-based, not server-based. Integrates easily into Python apps!
